# Using expect from Perl

Tags: perl, expect

I have a situation where in I am calling the below Perl script

```
if (param("lremail") && param("lot")) {
    my $address=param("lremailaddress");
    my $lot=param("lot");
    print a({-href=>"$dir/new.pl"},"Back to Top"),br;
    print "Request submitted for $address.",br;
    print "Lot $lot",br;
    print "You will receive an e-mail with a link to the data when the request is complete.";
    print end_html;
    system ("ssh SERVERNAME /test/abc.csh $lot $$ $address &");
    exit(1);
```

The above script does not run because when I execute the system is prompted for a password. Then I looked it up and found the below command..

```
> expect -c 'spawn ssh SERVERNAME /test/abc.csh J213520 06 abc@gmail.com "ls -lh file"; expect "Password:"; send "PASSWORD\r"; interact'
```

The above command is executed successfully without any issue but from the command line only. When I incorporate the same(by replacing the `system` call) within the Perl script, it fails.
How can I incorporate within the first script?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) module for Perl.

However, I tend to write straight expect scripts and call them from Perl. That way I can use the expect scripts on their own. But then, I used to do a lot of Tcl too.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for your reply. The below line works perfectly via command line but not with-in the script..
> expect -c 'spawn ssh SERVERNAME /test/abc.csh J213520 06 abc@gmail.com "ls -lh file"; expect "Password:"; send "PASSWORD\r"; interact'

How can I incorporate the same line in the perl script?

Comment: Try either of the things I mentioned in my answer.